# Mysql max user connections bug

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a really weird problem to me.

I'm trying to connect with an user to my mysql 5.5 instance but it keep saying to me that user already exceeded the max_user_connections

```
ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'xpto' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 100)
```

But,

```
show processlist
```

doesn't shows any connection used by that user. I'm pretty sure that user is not using any connection at all.
If i increase the current value to 110 for example i can connect. Then if i lower i can't connect.

**EDIT:** the global connections usage is 500 and only a few (10/20) are being used.

Any clue?

Comment: Connecting how and what is the value of max_user_connections?

Comment: Global max connections is 500 and for that user is 100. Connecting refused from mysql cli client and from a perl script that is the only thing that has this user to connect the database. And i kill every instance of that perl script too.

Answer (score 1):

The server has too many open connections already. A MySQL server can only handle a specific number of open connections before refusing to allow any more, and this limit is shared amongst all users of the server. It's usually set quite high, although it's easily possible for someone to effectively DoS a MySQL server by making lots of connections.

If you got the error message (code 1226) indicates that the entire MySQL server has run out of connection slots - this is the DoS scenario.

> 1. Your database must have a user ‘A’ using which you have configured your wordpress blog.
> 2. Now the problem is that user ‘A’ has exceeded `maximum_questions` resource (current value: 40)
> 3. Create a new user ‘B’ in your database through your domain control panel  and update the same user name you `wp-config.php` file in 
>      wordpress installation directory.
> 4. Now you got the problem fixed in few minutes. It will not disturb the database or the posts you have in your wordpress or phpbb.

Copied from [neuronring blog](http://blogs.neuronring.com/blogs/computer/troubleshooting/mysql-error-1226-user-has-exceeded-max_questions/)

Comment: No, as i said the user hasn't any connections if i run processlist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on MySQL 5, and you've set the user's MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS, and the user recently disconnected?

From MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html):

> For the MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS limit, an edge case can occur if the
>   account currently has open the maximum number of connections permitted
>   to it: A disconnect followed quickly by a connect can result in an
>   error (ER_TOO_MANY_USER_CONNECTIONS or ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED) if the
>   server has not fully processed the disconnect by the time the connect
>   occurs. When the server finishes disconnect processing, another
>   connection will once more be permitted.

Comment: I think that's not the case. I have no user connections reported by mysql and i can't connect during all day with that user. With root i can. I think a restart should resolve the issue, but i need to understand what's the problem to prevent in the future.